# How to get REALLY fast Python over a simple loop

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I'm working on a [SPOJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPOJ) problem, [INTEST](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/INTEST/).  The goal is to specify the number of test cases (n) and a divisor (k), then feed your program n numbers.  The program will accept each number on a newline of stdin and after receiving the nth number, will tell you how many were divisible by k.

The only challenge in this problem is getting your code to be FAST because `k` can be anything up to 10^7 and `n` can be as high as 10^9.

I'm trying to write it in Python and have trouble speeding it up.  Any ideas?

---

Edit 2: I finally got it to pass at 10.54 seconds.  I used nearly all of your answers to get there, and thus it was hard to choose one as 'correct', but I believe the one I chose sums it up the best.  Thanks to you all.  Final passing code is below.

Edit:  I included some of the suggested updates in the included code.

---

Extensions and third-party modules are not allowed.  The code is also run by the SPOJ judge machine, so I do not have the option of changing interpreters.

```
import sys
import psyco
psyco.full()

def main():
    from sys import stdin, stdout
    first_in = stdin.readline()
    thing = first_in.split()
    n = int(thing[0])
    k = int(thing[1])
    total = 0

    list = stdin.readlines()
    for item in list:
        if int(item) % k == 0:
            total += 1

    stdout.write(str(total) + "\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: have you tried reading bigger chunks? have you profiled it to see which operations are the most expensive? can you reduce the strength of the mod operation? can you use a mapping function to take advantage of their underlying c-based loops? I don't know that any of these will help, but it is clear that the problem isn't an algorithmic toughy...

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure about any of those things.  The whole reason I'm attempting to complete this problem is to see how fast I can get python to run, and how it can be optimized.  It's not about algorithmic difficulty it's raw speed in this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hey, I got it to be within the time limit. I used the following:

- Psyco with Python 2.5.
- a simple loop with a variable to keep count in
- my code was all in a main() function (except the psyco import) which I called.

The last one is what made the difference. I believe that it has to do with variable visibility, but I'm not completely sure. My time was 10.81 seconds. You might get it to be faster with a list comprehension.

Edit:

Using a list comprehension brought my time down to 8.23 seconds. Bringing the line `from sys import stdin, stdout` inside of the function shaved off a little too to bring my time down to 8.12 seconds.

Comment: Bloody hell, it sounds counterintuitive, but putting everything inside a function *does* work :P

Comment: Hm, edited the code to what now appears in the OP, and still no pass.  Is there a better way to call a main() function?

Comment: I didn't put in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` part. Also, I'd take out the else part of your list comprehension and put []'s around the expression inside the sum. I found that without the []'s it was much slower.

Comment: Module-level variables need to query and modify a hash table to get or set them.  Function-level variables need only index an array.

Comment: Jemfinch that's valuable information indeed.  My code is taking too long, but I feel we're getting somewhere.  Or at least that you're all dragging me there.  Thanks a lot to all of you, by the way.

Comment: @totallymike try just using a simple loop like you had at first (inside of a function of course). It was fast enough for me.

Answer (score 13):

[Edited to reflect new findings and passing code on spoj]

Generally, when using Python for spoj:

- Don't use "raw_input", use sys.stdin.readlines(). That can make a difference for large input. Also, if possible (and it is, for this problem), read everything at once (sys.stdin. readlines()), instead of reading line by line ("for line in sys.stdin...").
- Similarly, don't use "print", use sys.stdout.write() - and don't forget "\n". Of course, this is only relevant when printing multiple times.
- As S.Mark suggested, use psyco. It's available for both python2.5 and python2.6, at spoj (test it, it's there, and easy to spot: solutions using psyco usually have a ~35Mb memory usage offset). It's really simple: just add, after "import sys": import psyco; psyco.full()
- As Justin suggested, put your code (except psyco incantation) inside a function, and simply call it at the end of your code
- Sometimes creating a list and checking its length can be faster than creating a list and adding its components.
- Favour list comprehensions (and generator expressions, when possible) over "for" and "while" as well. For some constructs, map/reduce/filter may also speed up your code.

Using (some of) these guidelines, I've managed to pass INTEST. Still testing alternatives, though.

Comment: I didn't expect print to be a huge load as it's only called the one time.  I did include psyco in the source upon the next submit.  Didn't speed me up much, but it did multiply my memory footprint by a factor of ten, so at least they support it!

Comment: Of course, print shouldn't slow his submission down for this particular problem. That's why I mentioned "Generally" for these tips :)

They actually didn't include psyco when they started supporting python2.6, IIRC. But there was a huge outcry, so they "fixed" it ;)

BTW, python2.5 was faster everytime I tried it against 2.6. So that might also help...

Comment: Take a look at the updated list. With very few lines, you can pass this problem (and then you're free to keep on improving your time :))

Answer (score 6):

Use [psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/), it will JIT your code, very effective when there is big loop and calculations.

**Edit**: Looks like third party modules are not allowed,

So, you may try converting your loop to list comprehensions, it supposed to be run at C level, so it should be faster a little bit.

```
sum(1 if int(line) % k == 0 else 0 for line in sys.stdin)
```

Comment: Foreign modules not allowed as the code is run on their machine.

Comment: So i tried psyco, apparently it is supported.  Didn't speed me up enough but did add a memory footprint so I'm confident that it's there.

Comment: How large your stdin data, btw? I think it could only boost the speed when there is several thousands of loops or caculations in the data.

Comment: spoj doesn't let you see the test data, but they proclaim that you want to be able to handle 2.5M of input data per second.  The whole point of the problem is to see how fast your code can run.

Answer (score 3):

Just recently [Alex Martinelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli) said that invoking code inside a function, outperforms code run in the module ( I can't find the post though )

So, why don't you try:

```
import sys
import psyco

psyco.full1()

def main():

    first_in = raw_input()
    thing = first_in.split()
    n = int(thing[0])
    k = int(thing[1])
    total = 0
    i = 0

    total = sum(1 if int(line) % k == 0 else 0 for line in sys.stdin)

    print total
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

IIRC the reason was code inside a function can be optimized.

Comment: Put the psyco.full() right under the import psyco. Putting it inside the function makes it work very poorly. When I put it inside the main() function with my code, the code works just as fast as not using psyco at all.

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehensions with psyco is counter productive.

This code:

```
 count = 0
 for l in sys.stdin:
     count += not int(l)%k
```

runs twice as fast as

```
count = sum(not int(l)%k for l in sys.stdin)
```

when using psyco.

Answer (score 2):

For other readers, [here is the INTEST problem statement](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/INTEST/).  It's intended to be an I/O throughput test.

On my system, I was able to shave 15% off the execution time by replacing the loop with the following:

```
print sum(1 for line in sys.stdin if int(line) % k == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I've got the sum line in there and it seemed to speed me up, but not quite enough, unfortunately.